# IE sends empty POST body randomly while using NTLM authentication (using angular to Spring)

Tags: angularjs, spring, internet-explorer, authentication, ntlm

We are seeing issues with seemingly random calls that are missing the POST in IE 11.  Upon further inspection the requests from the browser are including a NTLM negotiation token.  We see this token on GETs too from time to time, but they are unaffected by the body problem as they don't have one.  Chrome and FF do not have this problem.

Further investigation shows that if our session times out and the browser is re-authed, then we will consistently see this problem after that at around 1 - 2 minute intervals.  It is my understanding that if IE "expects" a 401, then it will not include the POST body as is expects the NTLM handshake to take place again.

We have an angular app (currently mixed Angular 1 and 2, but occurred in 1 just before this).  The angular app makes restful webservice calls to our Spring boot application.  We are using waffle for NTLM auth

```
// Shiro-Waffle / Security
'com.github.dblock.waffle:waffle-parent:1.7.3',
'com.github.dblock.waffle:waffle-shiro:1.7.3',
'org.apache.shiro:shiro-core:1.2.3',
'org.apache.shiro:shiro-web:1.2.3',
```

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2010/11/21/challenge-response-authentication-and-zero-length-posts/

I have one crappy workaround that I will post below as an answer, but I do not like it at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I found a registry hack for this.  Basically IE proactively sends NTLM credentials without a 401 from the server.  When sending "pre auth" IE will omit the POST body (if the request was a POST.)  If the session was already valid and the server already has you authorized, it lets the request through without a body and will cause an error on the server (assuming the body is required for your POST.)

So a normal NTLM negotiation would look like

- request from client (with POST body) -> server returns 401 with
  www-authenticate:negotiate, www-authenticate:NTLM
- client sends
  additional request with NTLM token (w/o post body) -> server returns 401 with server
  NTLM token
- Client sends 3rd request with session (with POST body) and server returns
  200

With this optimization

- client expects 401 and sends NTLM token (w/o body) -> server returns 401 with server token
- Client sends 2nd request with session (with body) -> server returns 200

Problem occurs

- Client expects 401 and sends NTLM token (w/o body) -> server processes request and received internal error (probably 500)

Registry entry to add that prevents this "optimization"

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Internet Settings/ 
Add the following registry value: 
Value Name: DisableNTLMPreAuth
Data Type: REG_DWORD
Value: 1
```

Or Save these entries to a .reg file on your machine and double click on it

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\]
"DisableNTLMPreauth"=dword:00000001
```

I am not sure why IE thinks it has to re-auth, but from extensive testing it looks like once IE has a session timeout or the session is invalidated and it gets a 401 back from the server, it wants to re-auth every 1-2 minutes after that.  This could have something to do with what URL you are at at time of authentication as you may not be at the root.  The first link I provided talks a lot about IE's pickiness of URLs and how it guesses what should be authorized and what should not based on pathing.

Related articles:

[Zero Length POSTS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2010/11/21/challenge-response-authentication-and-zero-length-posts/)

[NTLM Pre-Auth](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2749007)

[NTLM Pre-Auth](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/251404)

[NTLM Pre-Auth jcifs](https://lists.samba.org/archive/jcifs/2006-September/006554.html)

Answer (score 1):

I have created a shiro filter that I put as the last filter in the chain (Groovy)

```
package com.security.shiro

import com.security.AuthenticateTrait
import com.ws.RemoteUserAccessor
import com.ws.RequestAccessor

import javax.servlet.ServletRequest
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse

/**
 * Created by esarrazin on 11/30/2016.
 */
class IEBugFilter3 extends NegotiateAuthenticationFilter implements RemoteUserAccessor, AuthenticateTrait, RequestAccessor {

/**
 * Returns <code>false</code> If the giant piece of sh1t IE chooses to think that it will need to re-authenticate
 * and not send the body to us.  Here we will deny access (as IE expects - big turd) and have waffle re-negotiate
 * this useless sh1t-bag.  Then and only then will IE choose to give us the body of the POST.  This problem is intermittent
 * and there is no telling when IE will use its infinite wisdom to do this, so please don't think if you comment this
 * out it is still working without.
 *
 * Not a silver bullet, but here is a link to some reading about this:
 * https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2010/11/21/challenge-response-authentication-and-zero-length-posts/
 *
 * @return Returns true if isAccessAllowed
 */
@Override
protected boolean isAccessAllowed(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, Object mappedValue) {
        !isRequestExpectingToReAuth(request, response)
}

private boolean isRequestExpectingToReAuth(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) {
    if (request?.request?.request?.coyoteRequest?.methodMB == 'POST' && toHttp(request).getHeader('content-length') == '0') {
        System.out.println("Found the dreaded zero length body and attempting to recover from it. $request.remoteHost")
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

}

Our NegotiateAuthenticationFilter extends waffle.shiro.negotiate.NegotiateAuthenticationFilter and is pretty straight forward.

This sees the empty body POST request coming across (forgive the request?.request garbage - not prod ready) and denies access, thus giving IE what it expects.  Since we are denying access, a 401 goes across and the handshake begins.  Then when the 200 is presented IE releases the body and we are AOK.  But this is crap- albeit a solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your workaround. I used it, and it works like a charm. Found your code comment so funny that I pasted it as well (referencing this post), hope you don't mind.

Comment: Forgot all about this one Chet.  Ha ha.  If you get a chance, give the answer a tick.

Comment: Of course, ticked it. See also here, by the way: https://github.com/Waffle/waffle/issues/806